# How to rebuild my reputation damaged by lies.?

Tags: management, colleagues

My manager transferred me and a colleague to places where we cannot afford to work. This is to protect himself from getting blamed for low sales. Manager didn't showed any interest in lively increasing sales profit but just kept adding new ranges so it could generate revenue in future. This has lead to low sales profit in the outlet I work. When taking sale/invoices, I performed well comparing to others. And manager says that he will transfer other people as well. He told a whole bunch of lies about me to the general manager (maybe, he did the same thing to other guys as well) and made my transfer reasonable. He told I'm not a team player which is not true. He kept putting me and other colleagues (who are being transferred right now) in embarrassing situations and created a culture where workers get benefits from backbiting. The guys who are being transferred are generally honest, didn't entertained this and kept refusing getting involved. Contrary to this all of us were best performers in our places. My whole reputation in the company is damaged. Maybe this is the reason why, one of my coworker who used to be my best friend outside office is not talking to me in-front of manager. I have some other job offers too. But I don't believe walking away as an option.

How can I correct my damaged reputation and gain trust of general manager again while recreating a good relationship with my manager.?

Comment: Is quitting an option? Find a good job and resign.

Comment: A last option might be going directly to the general manager.  This will most likely destroy your relationship with your current manager, but might be worth the effort if you stay and he goes.

Comment: Have you talked to this manager? It could be he doesn't feel they're lies, and he genuinely feels that way.

Comment: Why don't you believe walking away is an option? It takes a lot of courage to endure difficult situations. It takes even more courage to know when to quit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how it is salvageable and frankly, I don't know why you would want to.

One of my life mottoes is that "you can't protect against a liar". You can take whatever measures possible to minimize the chances that a person won't lie without being caught, but ultimately you have to have some trust. While it doesn't rank on the same level as relationship trust, employer-employee trust is pretty close. Your employer relies on you to do an honest job and to look out for the interests of the company where appropriate. In return, you rely on your employer to treat you fairly. Your manager (and by extension, your company) has violated that trust by telling lies and mistreating you.

You'll have a number of problems trying to make things work out. In order to repair something that's broken, both sides have to a) want to repair it and b) admit what they did wrong. I can't see a scenario where a boss who is willing to lie will do either.

Remember, it's always easier to find work while you're still employed.

Answer (score 1):

I see three options, since you can't fix someone who doesn't want to be fixed unless you have more authority than they do:

0) Have you tried assuming that there's a misunderstanding, talking to your manager, and trying to straighten out exactly what's being miscommunicated/misunderstood? "Never attribute to malice that which can be adequately explained by stupidity" -- or carelessness, or simple human error.

1) Tell higher management that there are personality conflicts between you and your manager (you don't have to outright call him a liar, just say the two of you don't work well together) and ask whether you can transfer to another department.

2) If you can't arrange that, I agree with those who suggest that it may be time to look at transferring yourself to another department... in another company.

I'd approach them in that order, personally. Moving within a company, for either personal or professional reasons, is far from uncommon. I initiated such a transfer in about my 5th year of employment, not because I disliked my management but because the project I was working on seemed to be dead and I wanted to both get out of that and do something different. Did it again a few years ago for similar reasons.

For what it's worth, the difficulty of changing assignments is usually proportional to how far up the management chain you have to reach to find someone who owns both your current job and the one you want to move into. Moving to a similar department in the same product group is definitely easier than changing divisions. And it's easier to get both approval and interest if you express interest in moving to something which is currently overloaded but not allowed to hire from outside.

An internal move does require overcoming whatever your current manager says about you. But managers often know how much to trust what their peers are saying, so if the problem really is him rather than you I think you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1):

You should plan to take the other job, but before you go – do some frank-talking research to learn as much as you can about what happened.

Be open to the possibility that you conducted yourself in a way that wasn't bad for sales, but maybe was not political (threatening to your boss when you could not reasonably advance, or some-such).  Ask people directly if they are avoiding you because they do not want associated ire from your boss(es), or if they heard an explanation of some bad / cocky behavior that they believe is true.  Be frank.  Speak with the assumption of fault and ask them to prove it otherwise.

Ask you boss directly why he said "abc xyz" that can be proven untrue by "123 jkl."  Be extremely polite and do not confront any more than your opening question.  Ask for his insight about growing / professional development.  If he makes false statements, don't confront, just defer them and keep him talking by stating that your experiences don't let you understand that position.

Take note after all meetings.

Before your last day / stated resignation, take all your notes and write them into a report on the issues confounding the company.  Send it to the head corp office, and ensure it gets to the boss of your boss's boss.  Use internal mail only if you can trust it won't be intercepted.

You cannot salvage the situation you're in, expect by right action, ethical conversation, and less fear.  9 lifetimes out of 10, you won't fix the situation you're in just by fearlessly embracing more ethical patterns.  If you do it well, you can show your work transparently to future employers, who will give you more reign to act in a leadership position.